# Automatically exporting time series of multiple polygons to .csv

Tags: remote-sensing, google-earth-engine, modis, nasa

I want to export data to a .csv file without having to display the chart. [Similar to what is done here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/exporting).

I want to skip the chart-display part because I'm working with long times series and if I try to display the chart I get the following error:"Error generating chart: Collection query aborted after accumulating over 5000 elements" as it is shown in the code below.

```js
var regions = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(    // San Francisco1.
    ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-122.79, 37.82, -122.6, 37.6), {label: 'SF1'}),
  ee.Feature(  // San Francisco2.
    ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-122.6,  37, -122.48, 36.7), {label: 'SF2'}),
 ]);
Map.addLayer(regions);

var chl = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/OCEANDATA/MODIS-Aqua/L3SMI")
    .filterDate('2003-10-25', '2017-08-25')
    .select('chlor_a');

// Create a time series chart.
var chltimeseries = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(
    chl, regions, ee.Reducer.mean(), 'chlor_a', 200, 'system:time_start', 'label')
        .setChartType('ScatterChart')
        .setOptions({
          title: 'Chlorophyl levels',
          vAxis: {title: 'mg/m3'},
          lineWidth: 1,
          pointSize: 4,
          series: {
            0: {color: 'FF0000'}, //SF1
            1: {color: '00FF00'}, //SF2
}});

// Display.
print(chltimeseries);
```

Comment: why would you want to do that? I mean, if you click in the icon top-right of the chart, you'll go to a new page where you can download it directly in csv. But I think there is no client-side function to perform exactly what you want. May be you could adapt the `Export.table.toDrive()` function..

Comment: I cannot build the chart because there is too much data (30 time series from 2000-2017) and I get an error. To do it the way you suggest I would have to do it in parts, which would be a waste of time. If you can point me in the direction of adapting the `Export.table.toDrive()` function, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I think you should paste your code (or a sample code which replicates the error) to get better answers.

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo, I just edited the question. It now shows a code that reproduces the error.